# Ignore intermediate array-wrapping objects in Jackson deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have some JSON that looks something like this:

```
{
    "name": "Michael",
    "interests": {
        "_total": 2,
        "values" : ["sports", "non-sport activities"]
     }
}
```

I want to deserialize it into an object like this:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    List<String> interests;
}
```

i.e. I don't want to include the array-wrapping object with the "_total" field.

In actuality I have a more complex json structure with multiple arrays, all wrapped in this way. How can I tell Jackson to discard these array wrappers and deserialize the arrays only?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@JsonProperty`

```
@JsonProperty("interests")
private void parseInterests(Map<String, Object> interests) {
     interests = (List<String>) brand.get("values");
}
```